# How to loop through an array in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

**HTML View**

```
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    Hi <span ng-click="changeName()" style="cursor: pointer;">{{firstname}}</span>
    </div>
```

**Model and Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstname = "Name 1";
    $scope.changeName = function() {
        $scope.firstname = "Name 2";
    $scope.changeName = function() {
        $scope.firstname = "Name 3";
     $scope.changeName = function() {
        $scope.firstname = "Name 4";
       $scope.changeName = function() {
        $scope.firstname = "Name 5";
    }
      }
}
}
});
```

Now the output is
"Hi Name 1"
Here Name 1 is clickable, when it's clicked Name 2 is shown..like that till Name 5. But I need to loop it. When Name 5 is clicked Name 1 should be shown again.

I'm bad in english. Please help.
[View it in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cupezuzx0IhQ9Vz4kenV?p=preview)

Comment: Please add plunker

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I have added plunker linker in description

Comment: where is the array?

Comment: try this https://plnkr.co/edit/sMf7m1OfEGiLhJU6XyIy?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [solution](https://plnkr.co/edit/FfSHVO1x7GOKhN7JTB4y?p=preview):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    var names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.changeName = function(){
        $scope.firstname = names[counter++ % names.length]; 
    }
    $scope.changeName();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, can i get a global code. If I replace Name 1 to "abc" and Name 2 to "def"..etc. Is there a solution to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, first you define an array with your required values and create a conditional statement inside your angular function

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.nameArray = ['Name 1', 'Name 2', 'Name 3', 'Name 4', 'Name 5'];
  $scope.firstname = "Name 1";
  var i = 1;
  $scope.changeName = function () {
    debugger;
    if (i < $scope.nameArray.length) {
      $scope.firstname = $scope.nameArray[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      i = 0;
      $scope.firstname = $scope.nameArray[i];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   
    Hi <span ng-click="changeName()" style="cursor: pointer;">{{firstname}}</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var arrayIndex = 0;
var arrayNames = ['name1','name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5'];
$scope.changeName = function() {
  $scope.firstname = arrayNames[arrayIndex];
  arrayIndex = arrayIndex+1>=arrayNames.length?0:arrayIndex+1;
};
$scope.changeName();
```